# Does this intermediate serie converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does $$\sum_{n≥2}\frac{1}{n (\ln(\ln n))^a}$$ converge if a>1 ?

I already know that $$\sum_{n≥2}\frac{1}{n (\ln n)^a}$$ and $$\sum_{n≥2}\frac{1}{n \ln n  (\ln(\ln n))^a}$$ converge if a > 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that for all $a$

$$\int_2^L \frac{1}{x(\log(\log(x)))^a}\,dx\overbrace{=}^{x\to e^{e^x}}\int_{\log(\log(2))}^{\log(\log(L))} \frac{e^{x}}{x^a}\,dx\to \infty \,\,\text{as}\,\,L\to \infty$$

the integral test guarantees that the series $\sum_{n=2}\frac{1}{n(\log(\log(n)))^a}$ diverges for all $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Let a > 0

$\sum\frac{1}{n (\ln(\ln n))^a}$ converges iff $\int\frac{1}{x (\ln(\ln x))^a}$ converges

however $\int\frac{1}{x (\ln(\ln x))^a}$ converges iff $\int\frac{1}{(\ln(t))^a}$ converges ( t = ln(x)) but $\int\frac{1}{(\ln(t))^a}$ diverges  by comparison ( $\ln(x)^a =o (\sqrt{x})$)